# generate increasing sequence in R

Tags: r, for-loop, sequence, replicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sequence of Repeated Values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432067/sequence-of-repeated-values-in-r)

I'm trying to generate an increasing sequence in R, with a total length of 5952. I have been writing it out by hand but I suspect there must be an easier way to do it. Here is the example:

```
v<- c(rep(1,96),rep(2,96),rep(3,96),rep(4,96), .... , rep(n,96)
```

Where n = 62. The result is a vector 5952 elements in length. One approach I thought might be useful is:

```
v = rep(NA, 96*62)
for(i in 1:62) {
v = c(rep(i,96))
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work, the result is just v = c(rep(62,96)). Any tips?

Comment: `v = c(v, rep(i,96))` insteed `v = c(rep(i,96))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
rep(1:62,each=96)

length(rep(1:62,each=96))
[1] 5952
```