# How to create a dataset in a specific structure?

Tags: r

I have a set of students `c("John","Jeff","Jim","Jack","Joe","Jones")` and each of them has attended in 3 different classes `c("Math","Science","History")` and achieved an natural number as score between 0 and 100.

Therefore, the table is supposed to be like

```
Name Class   Score
Jim  Math     25
Jim  History  60
Jim  Science  80
Jeff Math     85
Jeff History  40
Jeff Science  100
...
...
...
```

What i have tried is:

```
dt<-data.frame(
  Names=rep(c("John","Jeff","Jim","Jack","Joe","Jones"),3 ),
  Class=rep(c("Math","Science","History"),6  ),
  Grades=sample(1:100,18  ))

dt[sort(dt$Names),]
```

My code gives me:

```
   Names   Class Grades
4   Jack    Math     73
10  Jack    Math     87
16  Jack    Math     81
2   Jeff Science     24
8   Jeff Science     79
```

so, instead of `Math`, `History`, and `Science`, i have `Math`, `Math`, and `Math`.

But, it does not give me what i need. How can i fix it?

Comment: but "Jack" has attended only "Math" how is he supposed to get other subjects?

Comment: What do you mean? What is your original dataset? If it is `dt`, then the output you get is correct

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, that is why my code is wrong. I want `Jack` to have scores in `History`, and `Science` as well

Comment: @Sotos i have no original dataset. I am trying o generate my dataset

Comment: Ohh...I see. You are trying to "create" the data frame. Yup, you just need `each` in `rep` instead of `times`.

Comment: [Sequence of Repeated Values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432067/sequence-of-repeated-values-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `each` in `rep`... best practice is to set `each`/`times`/`length-out` in `rep` explicitly, to avoid unexpected behaviour.

```
data.frame(
  Names=rep( c("John","Jeff","Jim","Jack","Joe","Jones"), each = 3 ),
  Class=rep(c("Math","Science","History"), times = 6  ),
  Grades=sample( 1:100,18  ) )

# Names   Class Grades
# 1   John    Math     57
# 2   John Science     23
# 3   John History     82
# 4   Jeff    Math      3
# 5   Jeff Science     65
# 6   Jeff History     37
# 7    Jim    Math     95
# 8    Jim Science     39
# 9    Jim History     16
# 10  Jack    Math     18
# 11  Jack Science     63
# 12  Jack History     53
# 13   Joe    Math     90
# 14   Joe Science     11
# 15   Joe History     77
# 16 Jones    Math     29
# 17 Jones Science     15
# 18 Jones History     19
```

Comment: Wooe, i missed the `each` and the problem happened